# I'm getting the lcounter as correct but pcounter as random values like 32751. I don't that it's uninitiallized. Can anybody explain the issue?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, initialization, overflow

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1341/B
Codeforces says that in the line:
if(peaks>pcounter)
There is some unitialized error but Ithink I've initialized it.
I'm unable to understand the problem can someone help me with it?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{   using namespace std;
    int t,n,k;
    cin>>t;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {   int l,p,x,j;
        int lcounter=0;
        int pcounter=0;
        int peaks,pzero;
        cin>>n>>k;
        int height[n];
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        cin>> height[j];
        l=0;
        for(x=1;x<=k-2;x++)
        {
            if( ( height[x]>height[x-1] ) && ( height[x]>height[x+1] ))
               {
                   p++;
               }

            pzero=p;
            peaks=p;
        }
            pcounter=p;
        for(l=1;l<=n-k;l++)
        {   
            int x=0;
            int y=0;
            if(height[l]>height[l-1]&&height[l]>height[l+1])
            {
                x=1;
            }
            if(height[l+k-2]>height[l+k-1]&&height[l+k-2]>height[l+k-3])
            {
                y=1;
            }
            peaks+= -x+y ;

            if(peaks>pcounter)
            {
                pcounter=peaks;
                lcounter=l;
            }
        }
        cout<<pcounter+1<<" "<< lcounter+1<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something uninitialised say p C does, but C++ does not have to initialize by default.

Answer (score 0):

peaks is not initialized if k <= 2

Comment: It's given in the question that k>=3

Comment: Such errors are usually generated by some code analysis tool while compiling the code, and these kinds of tools tend to be *very* dump. And even if that tool would be smart, it probably doesn't know anything about the question.